# How to create an envelope recipient for a user in a group

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope created that is associated to a group, which when created properly sends an email to the users in the group and they can sign via that link, so everything on that end seems fairly functional.

The goal however is to be able to provide a portal for the users of the group to sign documents from, so we need to be able to make a recipient view for a group using the API.

**Using this request:**

```
/restapi/v2/accounts/<accountnumber>/envelopes/<envelopeId>/views/recipient
```

**With Headers:**

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication : 

{"Username":"<userEmail>","Password":"<pw>","IntegratorKey":"<key>"}
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "None",
  "email": "<email>",
  "returnUrl": "<httpsURL>",
  "userName": "<userName>",
}
```

---

This fails with

```
{
 "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
 "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

And through a lot of time and troubleshooting, I accidentally found out that if the user being used to authenticate the request itself in the header is part of the group that you will get a valid URL result, however the url is applicable to that user only no matter what userName/email combo you put into the request body.

It's as if docusign is defaulting to the user credentials making the request if it can't find any that work in the request body. Which... seems odd?

---

How does one properly make a docusign request view for a group via the API?

Comment: I have yet to try using signing groups to accomplish embedded signing, typically it's used for remote signing. If you can include any details on how you specified the clientUserID when creating the envelope I'd be interested to see that.

Comment: We use the recepientId, as the clientId all stored in our database. The documentation for clientId says ... "If userId is used and a clientUserId is provided, the value in the userId property must match a recipientId (which can be retrieved with a GET recipients call) for the envelope.". I've tried that and get "Invalid UserId". If I use v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/recipients I see the UserId's as a guid, which I've also tried and get UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT error.

Answer (score 0):

- The documentation does point out that "If a userId is used and a clientUserId is not provided, the userId must match the user ID of the authenticating user." via https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/
- If you are trying to return an embedded signing URL, it would need to include information about a specific recipient, as opposed to generalizing it to a group. DocuSign would need to return a signing URL for a specific user you specified.

Comment: The problem is for a group, you don't know the recipient on creation of the envelope. I've tried using the RecipientId, as the clientUserId, when creating the view for the group user and it doesn't work. I don't think the same relationship for clientUserId exists for the group (or any relationship, I've tried many combinations of various id's for clientUserId, to see if something would work). I think the hope was that if you had a group, and you specified a userName/Email it would after not finding a recipient search the group, and It doesn't quite seem to work that way.